# How do I manage to hide my ID field in my form

Tags: ms-access

So I have a form and a combo box that was made by the SQL code

```
SELECT [EmployeeID] & " " & [FirstName] & " " & [LastName] AS Employees
FROM Employees;
```

I use this to make a combo box but I want to hide the EmployeeID field from the combo box and not by removing EmployeeID from the SQL statement.

My current combo box is

Employee ID + " " + FirstName + " " + LastName

how do I change it to

FirstName + " " + LastName?

Help? D:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how you bind to a combobox.

If you want the combobox to only show the FirstName and LastName together, then the bound query for the `RowSource` of the combobox:

```
SELECT [EmployeeID],
       [FirstName] & " " & [LastName] AS EmployeeName
FROM Employees;
```

Then configure the combobox as follow:

[image: Data properties]

And set the first column width to `0` to hide it:

[image: Format properties]